# Azure Devops workitem migration from one account to another

Tags: migration, azure-devops, workitem

We have been trying to migrate the workitems from one AzureDevops account to our enterprise AzureDevops account using the vsts-work-item-migrator mentioned below. But the "Discussion Field" information is not getting migrated. Is this expected behavior or we missing something here.

https://mohamedradwan.com/2018/04/12/migrating-tfs-and-vsts-work-items-using-vsts-work-item-migrator/